# Check database for changes then reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm developing an script and I need it to check for changes in the DB.

Every time that `edit.php` is executed, it generates a timestamp and saves it in the DB. If a newer timestamp is saved in the DB, the `edit.php` page needs to be refreshed.

So, I created a page that shows the current timestamp saved on the DB (`checkupdates.php`), and make a JS-script check the page and compare the timestamps. If the DB one is newer, the page needs to be refreshed.

I have no notion of javascript, so far my page has no response for the current script.

Here is what I got until now:

**edit.php**

```html
<?php 
$date = new DateTime();
$utime = $date->getTimestamp(); //GET TIMESTAMP ON PAGE LOAD

updatetimestampondb($id, $utime); //UPDATE DB WITH CURRENT TIMESTAMP
?>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var updatetime = "<?php echo $utime; ?>"; //The timestamp saved in the DB when the page is executed

function checkUpdate() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'checkupdates.php?id=$id',
      timeout: 2000,
      success: function(data) {
        if (currentTS < updatetime) {
            alert('The page will be reaload');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}

setInterval(checkUpdate, 5000);

</script>
```

**checkupdates.php**

```html
<?php
(...) //Check DB Script for actual timestamp saved
echo "<script>var currentTS = ".$sheet->utime.";</script>";
(...)
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are doing it wrong, why are you echoing a JS code?

Comment: What is `$id` at `url: 'checkupdates.php?id=$id',`?

Comment: also a 2 second time out is very short. A small hiccup and it will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off sending a json response in the ajax as the js code will not work as such, try the following:

```
 $response = ["currentTS" => $sheet->utime];
 echo  json_encode($response);
```

And write your ajax like following(If the `$id` is a php var write it as `<?=$id?>`):

```
function checkUpdate() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'checkupdates.php?id=$id',
      timeout: 2000,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.currentTS < updatetime) {
            alert('The page will be reaload');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script>var currentTS = ".$sheet->utime.";</script>";
```

Will not work in an Ajax request. You need to send back JSON:

```
echo  '{"currentTS" : "'.$sheet->utime.'"}';
```

Then in the AJAX succes add `dataType: 'json'`:

```
data.currentTS < updatetime
```

---

Above will solve your problems with data coming back. However I do wonder why so elaborate. Couldn't you just make a request to server every 5 seconds and then dynamically update the components on your page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't echo javascript in a HTML script directly through AJAX.
What you could do is the following.

In `checkupdates.php` do

```
<?php 
   // ...
   echo $sheet->utime;
```

Then instead of the variable `data`, use the variable `currentTS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER UPDATE ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET @exec_var = sys_exec(CONCAT('node /path/to/node-js-script.js ', NEW.id));

END;
```

and catch the very exact moment when specific table was manipulated and emit event anywhere on the site you want.

And then you do not need anything like:

```
setInterval(checkUpdate, 5000);
```

... to cycle and send unwanted requests on each 5secs